# Regarding currency conversion error INR and USD

Tags: magento-1.8, currency, multicurrency, convert

I have a problem with currency convert, my base currency is Indian Rupee and i mapped Indian Rupee and [USD] to the site. Currency rates also given correctly. While i changed INR to USD its showing wrong prices in the site at category page and product page, in check out page its showing correct value. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Magento currency rates is manged from admin, so to `admin > system >Manage Currency >Rates`

and managed  currency symbol from `admin > system >Manage Currency >Symbols`

If want to add multiple currency then `goto admin > system > GENERAL > Currency setup> Allowed Currencies` .

More details:http://www.amitbera.com/get-currency-rates-for-a-multiple-currencies-in-magento/#sthash.471ye9oH.dpuf

I  thought, you have not converting price whenever you have called product price statis.

```
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currentCurrencyCode)->getSymbol();
$_coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');

$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),false,true);
 echo $currentCurrencyCode.''. $_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),false,true);
```